# Microsoft Store compliance failed due to gRPC

Tags: c#, windows, grpc

I have a Xamarin/UWP app that uses gRPC.  It includes the following nuget packages:

```
Grpc.Net.Client (2.42.0)
Grpc.Net.Client.Web (2.42.0)
Grpc.Tools (2.42.0)
```

When I submit the app to the Microsoft Store, I get the following failures:

```
API SymFromAddr in dbghelp.dll is not supported for this application type. grpc_csharp_ext.x64.dll calls this API.
API SymInitialize in dbghelp.dll is not supported for this application type. grpc_csharp_ext.x64.dll calls this API.
API SymSetOptions in dbghelp.dll is not supported for this application type. grpc_csharp_ext.x64.dll calls this API.
```

Any idea how to work around this?

Comment: Have you bundled the debug version of gRPC?

Comment: looks like a bug on grpc side: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/25789